# How to use unitest in a python project?

Tags: python, unit-testing

For example, I want to test airflow this project. the hierachy looks like this:

```
├── airflow
│   ├── model.py
│   ├── test
│   │   ├── test_model.py
```

I write a testcase to test the feature of the model, in test_model.py:

```
import unittest
from model import BaseModel

class TestModel(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
         print('here is the test logic')
```

How should I test it with command line?

What I tried was running `python -m unittest test/test_model.py` on `airflow` this primary directory.
but it raised error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.test_model'
```

Environment:

Python Version is `3.7`

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Any version less than 3.3 requires you to have `__init__.py` files in each directory that you would like to import modules from

Comment: @IainShelvington Just tested this, and both python 3.8 and 3.7 required `__init__.py`.

Comment: @IainShelvington Hi, I'm using 3.7

Comment: thanks alot, it's the `__init__` problem.